# How to write from eclipse's jar to Jmeter's log

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, jmeter

I would like to create jar in eclipse and to use it in Jmeter.
but if I want to write to Jmeter log how can I do it? 
for example if I have the next function

```
int sum (int a, int b)
{
   return a + b;
}
```

but I would like to add "the value of a is" + a;
In Jmeter log. 
all the code is in eclipse, and then I create a jar from It, and run it from Jmeter,I want that the user can see more info in Jmeter log,
is it can be done? to print to Jmeter log from the jar? that I create in eclipse? what to put inside my code in eclipse that can talk to Jmeter

Comment: How do intend to call your jar in JMeter? what are you extending?

Comment: I would like to do this manual https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTgwFadtPDc    and to write functions in eclipse and call them In Jmeter, and I want the user that will run the script will see extra info that I will write in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You are executing java code through JMeter.

Your code is executed and then you can log into JMeter Console using System.out:

```
System.out.println("Hello JMeter Console!");
```

Or you can add to JMeter log using Logger inside your code, for example:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

log.error("Hello JMeter Log!", new RuntimeException());
```